# Django api save to database (without REST frame work)

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

How can I do the following task using Django but without rest-framework?
For example, how can I save a User into my models?
This is my current code:

## serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User,Blog

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('std_num','password' , 'first_name',  'last_name', 'email')
```

## views

```
from rest_framework.views import  APIView
from rest_framework.response import  Response
from rest_framework import  status
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class register (APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        serializer = UserSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=111)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=100)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use django-rest-framework, since it currently does what you want?

Comment: It's a project and unfortunately, we're not allowed.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. You're not allowed *what*? What kind of project disallows using the best tool for the job?

Comment: A university project!

Comment: If you want help debugging an error, you have to provide a [mcve] and explain what the intended behavior and error is. "How do I implement this" is too broad for Stack Overflow. Be specific: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from .models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class register(View):
    def post(self, request):
        if not request.POST.get('password') or not request.POST.get('email'):
            #Do checking for other values 
            return_dict = {'status':False,'code':111}
        else:
           user_obj =User.objects.create(email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                  password=request.POST.get('password'))
           #save the needed values 
           user_obj.save()
           return_dict = {'status':True,'code':100}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(return_dict))
```

Check the 'code' or 'status' value in api response to do relevant actions

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create *User* object explicitly.This job is done by calling *serializer.save()*. It will be inefficient for you to create User by yourself. *Django* provides the built in functionality but if you want you can override it.